# Bios doesn't see hard drive and cd-rom

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios

I've spent several days trying to repair my hp pavillion desktop running Windows 7.  Through some boot USB applications it now can see the the USB drives but I cannot run the windows restore disks on a cd rom which tries to spin but never upto full speed.  I have also copied the contents onto a stick but it will only go until it's looking for a path and there's no drive to goto.  I was able to us a sata cable and power supply to transfer my all my files off HD so I'm OK with a complete wipe but I cannot get there.  How do I start over so it recognizes the hard drive and cd rom again?  FYI checked all cables and memory card connections.  Is my mobo hosed?

Comment: Did you reset the BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

How about a bootable USB windows restore disk or fresh windows install.

I did this once for a PC that wouldn't boot from the CD ROM drive.

1. Get a USB with a decent capacity 8-64 GB that you won't mind wiping the data from completely.
2. On another PC that has a CD ROM drive working, insert the windows installer disc, or find an iso download online, and also plug in the USB drive.
3. Open up a command prompt and type "diskpart" command, press enter.
4. Then type "list disk" and press enter.
5. Find out which Disk # your USB is associate with, based on its size, type "select disk #" where # is your Disk # and press enter
6. Type "clean" and hit enter.
7. Type "select disk #" where # is your USB's disk # and press enter.
8. Type "create partition primary" press enter.
9. Enter "select partition 1" press enter.
10. Type "active" press enter
11. Type "format fs=ntfs" enter and wait until it's formatted
12. Type "assign"
13. Type "exit"
14. Type "D: cd boot" where D is the drive associated with your CD rom, press enter
15. Type "cd boot" enter
16. Type "bootsect.exe /nt60 E:" where E is the letter of your USB drive at the moment, press enter
17. From here, restart your PC, you can either change the BIOS setting to boot from USB first instead of CD ROM or HDD by pressing the setup key (sometimes F2) or you can press the key to select which device to boot from (sometimes F12)

Hope this helps!

http://bootableusb.net/install-windows-7-usb-drive-easy-way/